# Django. How to annotate a object count from a related model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

lets say I have a model Comments and another model Answers. I want to query all comments but also include in the query the number of answers each comment has. I thought `annotate()` would be useful in this case, but I just don't know how to write it down. The docs write that:

> New in Django 1.8: Previous versions of Django only allowed aggregate
> functions to be used as annotations. It is now possible to annotate a
> model with all kinds of expressions.

So. This is an example of my models:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   ...

class Answer(models.Model):
   comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='answers')
```

And this is an example query:

```
queryset = Comment.objects.all().annotate(...?)
```

I'm not sure how to annotate the `Count` of answers each comment has. That is, how many answers point to each comment on the FK field `comment`. Is it even possible? is there a better way? Is it better to just write a method on the manager?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use [a `Count` aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
comments = Comments.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('answers'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Extra note: I had to add a `related_name` to my FK in order to make it work. Just in case someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be:

from django.db.models import Prefetch, QuerySet, Count

```
def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Customer]:
        return (
            Comments.objects
            .prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('answers', queryset=Answer.objects.only('id')),
                )
            .annotate(
                answers_count=Count('answers', distinct=True),
            )
            .order_by("-id")
            )
```

Please adjust according to specific scenario.