# How to effficiently get count of foreign keys in Django model?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models like this:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def get_house_count(self):
        fetchs = 0
        for fetch in self.fetchs.all():
            fetchs += 1
        return fetchs

class Person(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name="persons", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def get_person_count(self):
        person_fetchs = 0
        for fetch in self.person_fetchs.all():
            person_fetchs += 1
        return person_fetchs

class Fetch(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    house = models.ForeignKey(Hourse, related_name="fetchs")
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="person_fetchs")
```

What I want to achieve is to get the total number of each model instance in the Fetch class. But this operation is very expensive(over 500 duplicates) as it creates multiple SQL duplicates when I use the `django_debug_tool` library. Is there an efficient way to do this? My `view.py` file is like this:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    queryset = Fetch.objects.select_related(
        'house', 'person', )
    template_name = "index.html"
    paginate_by = 100
```

And in my template I have something like this:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ obj.company.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.house.get_house_count }}</td>                   
                <td>{{ obj.person.get_person_count }}</td>
```

I have also tried to use the django's annotate method like this:

```
queryset = Fetch.objects.select_related(
        'house', 'person', ).annotate(
        get_count=Count('house', distinct=True),
        get_contact_count=Count('person', distinct=True)
    )
```

while making changes to my template using `{{obj.get_count}}` and `{{obj.get_contact.count}}` respectively. But it returns a count of 1 which is wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with Person and House classes? What is Fetch for? Could you explain your goal in a non-technical way, please?

Comment: @oz19 Picture it as a dormitory with different people(Person) belonging to different houses(House). The fetch model stores how a housemaster picks students to perform different tasks. A particular person belonging to a house may be selected many times. Hence I want to find out the number of times that student was selected. Same with the House model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django. How to annotate a object count from a related model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356152/django-how-to-annotate-a-object-count-from-a-related-model)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It doesn't. I tried it already. But it returns a count of 1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your explanations in the comments and if I correctly understood...

I think you don't need the `house` field in Fetch model. The House is referred in Person with the ForeignKey. You neither need `number`, as you will see below.

So, your models would be much simpler, just something like these:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Person(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Fetch(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Now, guess we have the person Tom with id=1. He's been "fetched" 5 times by the housemaster to do whatever tasks. You simply need to do this to know how many times he's been "fetched":

```
tom = Person.objects.get(id=1) # Tom's Person instance
times_fetched = Fetch.objects.filter(person=tom).count()
# Result: 5
```

It is possible to use Python's len() to count the QuerySet elements after the filter, you can use any of them:

```
times_fetched = len(Fetch.objects.filter(person=tom))
# Result: 5
```

You can access Tom's house just doing this:

```
house = tom.house         # House instance
house_name = house.name   # Name of the house
```

You can also get the number of times a Person from an specific House has been "fetched":

```
house = House.objects.get(id=3) # Guess House ID is 3
times_fetched_from_house = Fetch.objects.filter(person__house=house)
```

In this case, it filters by that house with id=3. This is possible due to the relationship between Person and House (the ForeignKey).

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the repetition in my code with your answer. I just realised there was no need to add house object to my Fetch model. The filtering method you proposed only returns for a single id. Please how do I get count for all the ids?

Comment: I think Fetch.objects.all().count() is what you are looking for. If it is, I will update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, but thanks for your effort.